# Show headings only in sparse tree

Tags: org-mode

I am generating a sparse tree typically using a regex (, / r ). What I am trying to do is get an overview of where in my document a match occurs, not the exact positions of the matches. So, if I have a heading with several kilobytes of plain text underneath that contains a match, I don't want my sparse tree to show the plain text, only the relevant heading.

So, given a doc:

```
* H1
** H2.1
Foo
etc
** H2.2
Bar
** H2.3
Foo
etc
etc
```

And a sparse tree generated for regex foo, I would want to see something like

```
* H1
** H2.1
...
** H2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like **`outline-hide-body`** does exactly what you want:

```
Hide all body lines in buffer, leaving all headings visible.

Note that this does not hide the lines preceding the first heading line.
```

So after creating the sparse tree use <kbd>M-x outline-hide-body RET</kbd>.

Or create a custom command that calls `org-occur` and hides the body lines afterwards:

```lisp
(defun my-org-occur-and-hide-content ()
  "Interactively call `org-occur' and hide body lines after."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively #'org-occur)
  (outline-hide-body))
```

Call it with <kbd>M-x my-org-occur-and-hide-content RET</kbd>.

Result with the example from the question:

[image]